# Jquery Math with Multiple HTML tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have 12 tables, one for each month of the year. Each table row has a cell that displays a value. I would like to calculate the sum of these rows/cells for each table. Right now I'm using a script that looks like this from a preview answer, but to duplicate it 12 times is not working and it's a lot of code. Is there a shorter way I can do this?

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

$(window).load(function(){
var valueCells = document.querySelectorAll('.rowDataSdAugust');
var sum = 0;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    valueCells,
    function(valueCell) {
      sum += parseFloat(valueCell.innerText);
    }
);
var roughsum = sum /valueCells.length;
var finalsum = roughsum.toFixed(2);
document.querySelectorAll('.totalColAugust')[0].innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green;'>"+ finalsum + "% GAIN</h1>";
});

//]]> 
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

$(window).load(function(){
var valueCells = document.querySelectorAll('.rowDataSdJuly');
var sum = 0;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    valueCells,
    function(valueCell) {
      sum += parseFloat(valueCell.innerText);
    }
);
var roughsum = sum /valueCells.length;
var finalsum = roughsum.toFixed(2);
document.querySelectorAll('.totalColJuly')[0].innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green;'>"+ finalsum + "% GAIN</h1>";
});

//]]> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two arrays - one for table names and other for total column names. Then execute the same function number of times thru loop.

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

    $(window).load(function(){

        var tableArray = new Array("rowDataSdJanuary","rowDataSdFebruary","rowDataSdMarch","rowDataSdApril","rowDataSdMay","rowDataSdJune","rowDataSdJuly","rowDataSdAugust","rowDataSdSeptember","rowDataSdOctober","rowDataSdNovember","rowDataSdDecember");
        var totalColArray = new Array("totalColJanuary","totalColFebruary","totalColMarch","totalColApril","totalColMay","totalColJune","totalColJuly","totalColAugust","totalColSeptember","totalColOctober","totalColNovember","totalColDecember");

        for(i=0; i<tableArray.length; i++) {     

            var valueCells = document.querySelectorAll('.'+tableArray[i]);
            var sum = 0;

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(
                valueCells,
                function(valueCell) {
                  sum += parseFloat(valueCell.innerText);
                }
            );
            var roughsum = sum /valueCells.length;
            var finalsum = roughsum.toFixed(2);
            document.querySelectorAll('.'+totalColArray[i])[0].innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green;'>"+ finalsum + "% GAIN</h1>";            

        }        

    });

//]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: I give it a go but it didn't work for me. What Jquery library do you suggest using for this one?